# How can I perform this calculation in another program done, also in Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

This is done in Maple in steps (see picture) , and i want to do this on the same manner with steps in Mathematica.

[image]

Comment: Please include in your question the Mathematica code you tried and describe the problems you encountered.

Answer (score 3):

One possible way

```
ClearAll[f, t, u, v]
f[t_] := Exp[t + I*t]
HoldForm[f[t]] == f[t]
HoldForm[f[t]] == ComplexExpand[f[t]]
u[t_] := Exp[t]*Cos[t]
v[t_] := Exp[t]*Sin[t]
HoldForm[u[t]]==u[t]
HoldForm[v[t]]==v[t]

With[{integrand = u[t] + I*v[t]}, 
 HoldForm[Integrate[integrand, t]] == Integrate[u[t], t] + I*Integrate[v[t], t]
]

defint = Integrate[u[t], {t, 0, Pi/2}] + I*Integrate[v[t], {t, 0, Pi/2}];

With[{f = f[t]}, HoldForm[Integrate[f, {t, 0, Pi/2}]] == defint]
```

Gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thank you , its very helpful! ( its one possible way?)
A question rise :  compare the outputs of both programs. 
- MMA simplifies it more then Maple does default , that's good
Further simplification with Maple expression here is possible, but for speciazilized  user. 
I did a few calculations with Maple and the endresult was not similar with a bookform. (although by hand i get the wanted bookform).
I am curious if MMA can do it better to arrive on a bookform result. 
Later on i will face Maple procedures converted to MMA ( study this ).

Comment: "I am curious if MMA can do it better to arrive on a bookform result."  but Mathematica final result is exactly the same as the book output you show on the first line in your post.  It just written with `1/2` factored outside instead of in the denominator. Also the `I` is factored out in the second term. Or Am I missing something here?

Comment: You did the calculation right here , but  i did some other calculations in the past what deliver not a "bookform"result in Maple.
Looks like MMA does come up with a "book form" in other calculations i will  do( at least I hope so).

Comment: if it is something else, then may be you could post a separate question on that issue, asking how to obtain the same book form of the result vs. what Mathematica showed. And please include the code you used. btw, there are lots of commands to Manipulate expressions to the form you want that you could use in Mathematica. Same as with Maple.

Comment: It was not possible to get a simplification to  a "bookform" in Maple on some calculations done by Maple specialist.    
The expression ends on   expr1 / expr2 , while the wanted bookform looks like  expr1 x ( expr2/expr3).
Perhaps you get the idea ?

Comment: Can't find the two Maple example easy back  , so let me focus then on new calculations with MMA.

Comment: Would like to continue with new problems.
The beginning on this forum was difficult with the editor
I am currently unable to post questions on the forum.
Have improved the questions and now hope that the ban will be lifted again to be able to ask questions again?

Comment: @janamdo Please contact a moderator for any issues if you are not able to post questions for some reason. I am not a moderator.

Comment: yes i did contact a moderator . Unfortanely it was a unlucky start here on the forum and complicated